# how to fix a form and get response from api using cURL

Tags: php, json

I have made a HTML form and when I hit upgrade I would like it to use the API and display the result.

```
<form action="upgrade.php" method="POST"><input name="k" placeholder="Key" style="border-radius: 4px;background-color: #efefef;border: grey;margin-bottom: 2%;width: 35%;padding: .6rem .75rem;" type="text" /><br />
<label><b>Country</b></label><br />
<br />
<select name="c" style="border-radius: 4px; background-color: #efefef; border: grey; margin-bottom: 2%; width: 35%; padding: .6rem .75rem;"><option value="AR">Argentina Remaining: 4324</select>

<p style="text-align: center;"><b>Invites Remaining: 35068</b></p>
<br />
<input class="btn btn--green-bg" style="margin: 0px;" type="submit" value="Upgrade!" /></form>
```

Code

```
<?php 

// $postRequest = array(
    // 'firstFieldData' => 'key',
    // 'secondFieldData' => 'countrycode'
// );

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$cURLConnection = curl_init("https://upgrader.cc/API/v2/?key=" . $_POST['k'] ."&country=".$_POST['c']);
//curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postRequest);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$apiResponse = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
curl_close($cURLConnection);

// $apiResponse - available data from the API request
$jsonArrayResponse = json_decode($apiResponse);
$array = json_decode(json_encode($jsonArrayResponse), True);
$response = @json_decode($abc);
if (($response) && (true === $response->success)) {
    echo $array["data"]["token"];
    echo $array["data"]["address"];
} else {
    echo $array["message"];
    }


?>
```

Here is API keys failed answer:

```
{"status":"failure","message":"Failure Reason"}
```

And the success answer:

```
{"status":"success","data":{"token":"Token Link","address":"Address","used_total":"Used Total","useable":True / False}}
```

When I use this code, I get one answer, but I can't get it to do success or fail only one or the other

```
<?php 

// $postRequest = array(
    // 'firstFieldData' => 'key',
    // 'secondFieldData' => 'countrycode'
// );

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$cURLConnection = curl_init("https://upgrader.cc/API/v2/?key=" . $_POST['k'] ."&country=".$_POST['c']);
//curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postRequest);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$apiResponse = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
curl_close($cURLConnection);

// $apiResponse - available data from the API request
$jsonArrayResponse = json_decode($apiResponse);
$array = json_decode(json_encode($jsonArrayResponse), True);

echo $array["message"];
?>
```

Comment: can you add print_r($apiResponse);
or var_dump($apiResponse); to see the json data returns by the api. then update your post with it.

Comment: hi i have updated the post to show where im at now

Comment: Your response is not returning any result. you want print the value of invites but there was no invites in the json array returned

Comment: I really cannot understand your code. see my answer

Comment: hi nancy where should i put print_r($apiResponse);

Comment: see my answer first. just send the key and country parameter direct in my code  and let me know what happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. Let me see what your  json response will be. Do it now ....

You will need to check the api is a post request or get request eg.

```
<?php
    // set value of k and country...
    $yourkey =$_POST['k'];
    $country =$_POST['c'];


// make sure that key and country is not empty and exit.
    if($yourkey ==''){
echo "key is empty";
exit();
}

    if($country ==''){
echo "country is empty";
exit();
}

    $url_post ="https://upgrader.cc/API/v2/?key=$yourkey&country=$country";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url_post);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    // Send post request
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); $result_post = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    print_r($result_post);


?>
```

**updated section**

here you can print messages and status returned by json call and avoid the issue you are having

```
<?php
    // set value of k and country...
    $yourkey =$_POST['k'];
    $country =$_POST['c'];


// make sure that key and country is not empty and exit.
    if($yourkey ==''){
echo "key is empty";
exit();
}

    if($country ==''){
echo "country is empty";
exit();
}

    $url_post ="https://upgrader.cc/API/v2/?key=$yourkey&country=$country";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url_post);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    // Send post request
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); $result_post = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    //print_r($result_post);



$json = json_decode($result_post, true);
$status = $json['status'];
$message = $json['message'];


if($status == 'failure'){
// print message
echo "Failure message is here: <b>$message</b>";

}


// assuming status value is success
if($status == 'success'){
// print message
echo "success message is here: <b>$message</b>";

}



?>
```

Comment: hi i cant post it all in here but <!DOCTYPE html> <html style="height:100%"> <head><title> 400 Bad Request </title>

Comment: what do you enter here in my code $yourkey =' your key here';
$country ='country goes here';

Comment: bad request because country and your key is not sent. If you still want to pass it in a form input  then remove `$yourkey =' your key here';
$country ='country goes here'; ` and  uncomment  `$yourkey =$_POST['k'];
$country =$_POST['c']; `

Comment: i use my php form and enter a valid key and country

Comment: ok now we are going somewhere lol     {"status":"failure","message":"This account seems to still be premium! If this is a mistake, please try again later."}

Comment: hello any issue. whats is going on

Comment: so this comes back with {"status":"failure","message":"This account seems to still be premium! If this is a mistake, please try again later."}   which is correct i think

Comment: That account key is talking about premium whatever.  you will need to contact the site API owner to know what is going on

Comment: Nancy it is working perfectly, i just need to clean up the output to remove these parts {"status":"failure","message":"

Comment: I do not understand what you mean its okay, its returning an error message status failure and what do you mean by i just need to clean up the output to remove these parts {"status":"failure","message":" –

Comment: its in the api Failed replies: 
        {"status":"failure","message":"Failure Reason"}      so the api is displaying everything like this {"status":"failure","message":"This account seems to still be premium! If this is a mistake, please try again later."}

Comment: so that response is correct, i just need to figure out how to hide the { and "

Comment: sorry for being late just taken away by sleep. I have updated my answer to show how you can print status and messages to avoid those things you may be complaining. see updated section of my answer. please also upvote my answer if you like it. thanks

Comment: hi nancy the failed response works perfectly, the success line gives no output now. it comes like this success message is here:

Comment: copy the code and send it to the api company and ask them to know what is happening on their end. Thanks

Comment: hi nancy, i have spoke to them they said this                                                          $info = file_get_contents("https://upgrader.cc/API/v2/?info=$key%22);
$info = json_decode($info);


then you can simply access the object like "$status = $info->status;" or a nested object like "$token = $info->data->token;"
Hope this helps

Comment: hi nancy, thanks for all your help, i got there in the end

Comment: Its not easy my brother. am glad I could help. Thanks and good luck